# Scala: Making config data as a global object

Tags: scala

I have a case class for configuration parameters which is populated (using NO external library) before starting the actual application.
I pass this config object through out the application and in too many places.
Now the question is can this object be made global so I can refer it across the application as the values are going to be constant.

```
case class ConfigParam() extends Serializable {
  var JobId: Int = 0
  var jobName: String = null
  var snapshotDate: Date = null
}
val configParam = ???

val ss = getSparkSession(configParam) //Method call...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ConfigParam as a global object could have bad implications for you. First of all, it will make harder to test any function which is using that global object.

Maybe you could just pass `ConfigParam` as an implicit argument?

For example, let's say you've got 3 functions:

```
def funA(name: String)(implicit configParam: ConfigParam): String = ???
def funB(number: Int)(implicit configParam: ConfigParam): String = ???
//you don't have to explicitily pass config param to funA or funB
def funC(name: String)(implicit configParam: ConfigParam): String = funA(name) + funB(100)

implicit val configParam = ??? //you need to initialise configParams as implicit val
funC("somename") //you can now just call funC without explicitly passing configParam
                 //it will be also passed to all function calls inside funC
                 //as long as they've got implicit parameter list with ConfigParam
```

Another solution could be to use some kind of dependency-injection framework, like [guice](https://github.com/google/guice).

Comment: Thank you. So will this also apply to a different function say `funD` on a different `package` if I declare ConfigParam as an implicit argument.

Comment: Yes, if the function, which is calling `funD` will have ConfigParam passed as an implicit parameter to it.